# How to use two custom authentication and authorization guard at the same time in nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, nestjs, authorization

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '../user/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User>,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
        secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
      });
      const user = await this.userModel.findById(payload.id);

      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('User not found.');
      }
      request['user'] = user;
      console.log('request.user -->', request.user);
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'You are not authorized to access this resource.',
      );
    }
    return true;
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}
```

**role.guard.ts**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Role } from '../enums/role.enum';
import { ROLES_KEY } from '../decorators/roles.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const isAuthorozed = requiredRoles.some(
      (role) => user.role?.includes(role),
    );

    if (!isAuthorozed) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException({
        message: 'You are not authorized person to access this resource.',
        statusCode: 401,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**role.decorator.ts**

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Role } from '../enums/role.enum';

export const ROLES_KEY = 'roles';
export const Roles = (...roles: Role[]) => SetMetadata(ROLES_KEY, roles);
```

**book.controller.ts**

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Roles(Role.USER)
  @Get()
  async getAllBooks(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Query() query: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const books = await this.bookService.findAll(query);
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
      data: books,
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'Books fetched successfully.',
    });
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI'),
        dbName: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    BookModule,
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
```

In my scenario i have used two custom guards that is authentication and role based authorization. If i use both of them in book controller (i have mentioned in above code) it ignores `AuthGuard` and it directly executes `RoleGuard`.

But i wanted to be executes first `AuthGuard` as i need user details to check user role in `RoleGuard`.

Thank in advance.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `RolesGuard` is a global guard it would be executed upfront before `AuthGuard`. It seems to me that `AuthGuard` should be defined in `AppModule` level instead of controller level:

Add `AuthGuard` in **app.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI'),
        dbName: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    BookModule,
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
```

Also you should remove `AuthGuard` from `book.controller.ts` since it would be executed from the App Module.

Comment: This enables authentication globally, so that i have to create Public decorator and use it into public routes. This make sense. Thanks